# gridview can't get the last row from the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

I have an c sharp desktop application the user wants me to make the same into a web application, i have a datagrid on the desktop application and added a gridview on my webform.

Also have a button named last record when clicked returns the last row of the data grid view:

```
 net_Weight_TrackingDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = net_Weight_TrackingDataGridView.RowCount - 1;
```

I am trying to get the same functionality to work in grid view:

my grid view has these turned on:

this.GridView1.AllowPaging = true;

this.GridView1.AllowSorting = true;

because i have a lot of data and if i set the above to false the page keeps loading and loading.
for the last row i tried:

```
GridViewRow LastRow = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
```

The above piece of code is not working....

Any help will be generously appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some contextual code and the actual error that you are seeing?  It is hard to determine what could be wrong based on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3(v=vs.140).aspx):

> 1. If the GridView control is bound to a data source control that is
>      capable of returning a single page of data when requested, the
>      GridView control will take advantage of that capability directly.
> 2. If the GridView control is bound to a data source control that does
>      not support the paging capability directly, or if the GridView control
>      is bound to a data structure in code through the DataSource property,
>      the GridView control will perform paging **by getting all of the data
>      records from the source**, displaying only the records for the current
>      page, and discarding the rest.

So,

```
this.GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
this.GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
```

work only if you have case #1. If you have case #2, asp.net will request all data and this is why your page is slow. To avoid this situation you either need to use data source control as per case #1 or even better implement custom paging so that your query does not return all rows from the database, but only X required rows.

Read about custom paging ([example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/))